# Handling errors in a PHP class

Tags: php, class, error-handling

I try to handle errors in a class written in PHP and using curl, this class uses 3 functions (init, sendFirstForm, sendSecondForm) dependent on one another, I test result via nested statements.

I want to manage two types of errors (Curl connection errors and form errors) that requires the sending of an email so I can fix them.

This code does not work.

```
class Sender {

    public $error;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->error = '';
    }

    public function send() {

        if($this->init() === TRUE) /* account login and retrieval of the cookie */
        {
            if($this->sendFirstForm() === TRUE) /* sending the first form if connection  */
            {
                if($this->sendSecondForm() === TRUE) /* sending the second form if connection  */
                {
                    echo 'Annonce publiée avec succès.';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function init() {

        // CuRL : account login and retrieval of the cookie
        // ...
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if(curl_errno($ch))
        {
            $this->error = 'CuRL Error : ' . curl_error($ch);
            return $this->error;
        }
        elseif(preg_match("/\bError\b/i", $result)) /* $ _POST data missing and / or incorrect */
        {
            $this->error = 'Error in the login form';
            return $this->error;

            mail('name@domain.com', 'Error Curl', 'Error connecting to the account, here are the data sent : ' . $postfields);
        }
    }

    public function sendFirstForm() {

        // CuRL : sending the first form
        // ...
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if(curl_errno($ch))
        {
            $this->error = 'CuRL Error : ' . curl_error($ch);
            return $this->error;
        }
        elseif(preg_match("/\bError\b/i", $result)) /* $ _POST data missing and / or incorrect */
        {
            $this->error = 'Error in the first form';
            return $this->error;

            mail('name@domain.com', 'Error Curl', 'Error sending first form, here are the data sent : ' . $postfields);
        }
    }

    public function sendSecondForm() {

        // CuRL : sending the second form
        // ...
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if(curl_errno($ch))
        {
            $this->error = 'CuRL Error : ' . curl_error($ch);
            return $this->error;
        }
        elseif(preg_match("/\bError\b/i", $result)) /* $ _POST data missing and / or incorrect */
        {
            $this->error = 'Error in the second form';
            return $this->error;

            mail('name@domain.com', 'Error Curl', 'Error sending second form, here are the data sent : ' . $postfields);
        }
    }
}

$send = new Sender();
$send->Send();

if(empty($send->error))
{
    // MySQL treatment
}
else
{
    echo $send->error;
}
```

Comment: This question would be better for CodeReview rather than SO..

Comment: "Is the logic is correct?" - ....does it run as intended? If so, the answer is "as far as I know, yes" and your question is on-topic on [codereview.se]. If the code does *not* run as intended, then the answer is "apparently not" your question is off-topic on code review, and *would be* a good Stack Overflow post *if* you [edit] the post into a [mcve] depicting the *specific* problem you're facing. Good luck!

Comment: I would have an error error that i would put the error messages in. Just test that array not be empty at the end processing and send the emails and/or whatever other error reporting processing is required. Easy to maintain as it is `DRY`.